# MVP - Presenter comparision: view injected in constructor vs takeView(View v) / dropView()

Tags: java, android, dependency-injection, mvp, android-mvp

I've seen two approaches to MVP pattern in Android. Both are used in [Android Architecture Blueprints](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture):

```
public interface Contract {
    interface View {
        void showData(String data);
    }

    interface StartVersionPresenter {
        void start();
    }

    interface DropViewVersionPresenter {
        void takeView(View view);
        void dropView();
    }
}
```

1) The presenter in which the view is **injected via the constructor**:

```
public class StartVersionPresenter implements Contract.StartVersionPresenter {

    private final Contract.View view;
    private final Repository repository;

    public StartVersionPresenter(Contract.View view, Repository repository) {
        this.view = view;
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    @Override
    public void start() {
        loadData();
    }

    private void loadData() {
        repository.getData(new DataCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onDataLoaded(String someData) {
                view.showData(someData);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

`start()` is called in `onResume()` `Fragment`'s method.

2) The presenter in which the view is **injected via the method (`takeView` in my example)**:

```
public class DropViewVersionPresenter implements Contract.DropViewVersionPresenter {
    private final Repository repository;
    private Contract.View view;

    public DropViewVersionPresenter(Repository repository) {
        this.repository = repository;
    }


    @Override
    public void takeView(Contract.View view) {
        this.view = view;
        loadData();
    }

    @Override
    public void dropView() {
        view = null;
    }

    private void loadData() {
        repository.getData(new DataCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onDataLoaded(String someData) {
                if (view != null)
                    view.showData(someData);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

`takeView(Contract.View view)` is called in `Fragment`'s `onResume()` method.
`dropView()` is called in `Fragment`'s `onDestroy()` method.

In both cases the presenter is created in `Fragment`'s `onCreate()` method.

Why does the second approach is used in more cases rather then the first one? I can see that the first one is simpler because we don't have to check that the view is not null if we want to call the method on it.